# Install older version of Kong on macOS

Tags: macos, macos-mojave, kong

Right now I have Kong v1.0.2 installed with brew. I'm using macOS Mojave.

When I search for older versions (`brew search kong`) I didn't found any other versions.

I want to install 0.14.1 since I have some custom plugin that works with Kong v 0.x only.

I tried `brew install kong@0.14.1` with no success.

> Error: No available formula with the name "kong@0.14.1"

How can I install an older version of Kong?

Comment: Looks like the homebrew docs point to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54405176/install-older-version-of-kong-on-macos). Installing from a specific commit might be a good bet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution to install a particular older version for Kong. Why not give a try with docker:
link: https://opensource.com/resources/what-docker
image kong: https://hub.docker.com/_/kong

Comment: I tried with docker and it's working! It would be nice to have a docker free solution for macOS but, for now, this is good enough. Thanks!